# The argument type 'string?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String"

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, flutter-test

What are the errors about this code? Please can you make it correct and send me the code?

**4 positional argument(s) expected, but 2 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.**

**Undefined name '_formKey'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.**

**Undefined name '_authData'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.**

**Undefined name '_passwordController'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.**

**Undefined name '_passwordController'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.**

**The function '_submit' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines '_submit', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named '_submit'.**

**Expected a method, getter, setter or operator declaration.
This appears to be incomplete code. Try removing it or completing it.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../models/authentication.dart';

import 'home_screen.dart';
import 'login_screen.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
static const routeName = '/signup';
@override
_SignupScreenState createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {

final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();

Map<String, String> _authData = {
'email' : '',
'password' : ''
};

void _showErrorDialog(String msg)
{
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
      title: Text('An Error Occured'),
      content: Text(msg),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Okay'),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
          },
        )
      ],
    )
   );
  }

  Future<void> _submit() async
 {
  if(!_formKey.currentState!.validate())
  {
    return;
  }
 _formKey.currentState!.save();

 try{
  var key = 'email';
  await Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false).signUp(
      _authData[key],
      _authData['password']
  );
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);

  } catch(error)
 {
  var errorMessage = 'Authentication Failed. Please try again later.';
  _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
 }
}
}
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Signup'),

    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Login'),
            Icon(Icons.person)
          ],
        ),
        textColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(LoginScreen.routeName);
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Colors.limeAccent,
                  Colors.redAccent,
                ]
            )
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //email
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validator: (value)
                      {
                        if(value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@'))
                        {
                          return 'invalid email';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value)
                      {
                        _authData['email'] = value!;
                      },
                    ),

                    //password
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                      obscureText: true,
                      controller: _passwordController,
                      validator: (value)
                      {
                        if(value!.isEmpty || value.length<=5)
                        {
                          return 'invalid password';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value)
                      {
                        _authData['password'] = value!;
                      },
                    ),

                    //Confirm Password
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Confirm Password'),
                      obscureText: true,
                      validator: (value)
                      {
                        if(value!.isEmpty || value != _passwordController.text)
                        {
                          return 'invalid password';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value)
                      {

                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text(
                          'Submit'
                      ),
                      onPressed: ()
                      {
                        _submit();
                      },
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
       )
     ],
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atg3S.png)

Comment: Your `build` method is not inside of `State` class. Better code formatting will help you find it next time.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined messages because your build function is outside of the _SignupScreenState class, so just put it inside and those errors will be fixed. And about **4 positional argument(s) expected, but 2 found. Try adding the missing arguments.** error, it's probably that your signUp function requires two more arguments, but I don't have source code of it so I can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../models/authentication.dart';


class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/signup';

  @override
  _SignupScreenState createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'email': '',
    'password': ''
  };

  void _showErrorDialog(String msg) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (ctx) =>
            AlertDialog(
              title: Text('An Error Occured'),
              content: Text(msg),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Okay'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Signup'),

        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Login'),
                Icon(Icons.person)
              ],
            ),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(LoginScreen.routeName);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Colors.limeAccent,
                      Colors.redAccent,
                    ]
                )
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: 300,
                width: 300,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //email
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                              return 'invalid email';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            _authData['email'] = value!;
                          },
                        ),

                        //password
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                          obscureText: true,
                          controller: _passwordController,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty || value.length <= 5) {
                              return 'invalid password';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            _authData['password'] = value!;
                          },
                        ),

                        //Confirm Password
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Confirm Password'),
                          obscureText: true,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty ||
                                value != _passwordController.text) {
                              return 'invalid password';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {

                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text(
                              'Submit'
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _submit();
                          },
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _submit() async
  {
    if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState!.save();

    try {
      var key = 'email';
      await Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false).signUp(
          _authData[key],
          _authData['password']
      );
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);
    } catch (error) {
      var errorMessage = 'Authentication Failed. Please try again later.';
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not work Josteve another error has come.I added the code in Answer section.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
  var key = 'email';
  await Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false).signUp(
      _authData[key],
      _authData['password']
  );
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);
} catch (error) {
  var errorMessage = 'Authentication Failed. Please try again later.';
  _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
  }
 }
}
```

[image: error image]

Answer (score 0):

I am referring to your comment on my previous answer, so no, I can't give you my number, that's not the right way to ask for help, I guess that this site is made for that reason. I reproduced your error and solved it with the explanation written in the comments which you can see in the picture bellow.

[image]

So the right way to call your signUp method would be:

```
Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen:false).signUp(
    authdata['email'] as String,
    authdata['password'] as String,
    'pass third argument here',
    'pass fourth argument here',
  );
```